# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'type_article_id' in 'field list'

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have three columns: `article`, `type_article` and `theme`.
The article table has two foreign keys, which are `type` and `theme.`

**Article migration**

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('article', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id_article');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('type');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('theme');
        $table->string('titre');
        $table->string('contenu');
        $table->date('date_creation');
        $table->foreign('type')->references('id')
            ->on('type_article')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('theme')->references('id')->on('theme')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

**Article model**

```php
class Article extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'article';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id_article';
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function type_article()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Type_Article::class);
    }

    public function theme()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Theme::class);
    }
}
```

Type_article and Theme has this (except the end 'type' for 'type_article' and 'theme' for 'theme' :

```
public function article()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Article', 'type');
}
```

They both have a primary key `id.`

What I'm trying to do here is to fill a simple form with a title, an article type (with `foreach loop` inside my view (it's working), a theme, and content.

As you can see, inside the error message `(SQL: insert into article (type_article_id, theme, titre, contenu, date_creation)`. There are only five elements; the id of the article is not there. II do not have a `type_article_id` inside my table, I don't really know where it comes from, but I do create an `article_id`

Comment: The issue is coming because you define "type (type_article)" as a foreign key. 

```$table->foreign('type')->references('id')->on('type_article')->onDelete('cascade');```

it is inbuilt functionality of the Laravel to search for the column refer as it's foreign+table+name_id.

the best way to remove foreign fey from migration and handle it at the code level.

Comment: So I should remove `unsignedBigInteger` and put `int` + remove the lines with `foreign` ?

Comment: else you can rename your column from "type" to "type_article_id".

Comment: I personally believe that the user should not implement a foreign-key relationship at Schema/Migration level. because it not only slows the query operation but also sometimes generate DB-Error. although these are not very difficult to handle, you should avoid designing foreign-key relation in migration.

you should handle such relationship at code level not at DB level. So it not only improve DB operation but also you can feel safe at the time of delete/update operation in DB.

Comment: what do you mean by `code level` ? Where should I do that then ?

Comment: also, it would be good practise to pluralize your function name as "articles", because it refers to hasMany relationship.

Comment: delete foreign-key relation from migration. and rename column from "type" to "type_article_id". it will solve your problem.

Comment: By deleting, you mean delete the lines with `foreign` ? What about the `unsignedBigInteger` ?. But one question, the relation in the model `hasMany` and `belongsTo` are enough to say that there are foreign keys ? Also, I do need to do `php artisan migrate` ?

Comment: yes, "hasMany", "belongsTo" and any other relation are enough within itself. means if you have the "hasMany" relation in your Model (not in migration), then the Laravel will look for its reference-model with _id.

for example, you have a model name author and book. so the author might have multiple books. then in Author Model, we will design a relation like ```public functions books() { return $this->hasMany(Book::class) }``` 
Now, if we have a column named "author_id" into "book" DB-Table, then Laravel will automatically figure-it-out about the relationship between these two tables.

Comment: I understand. In my case, One article can have One type (so `belongsTo`) and type can have alot of article (so `hasMany)`. Now, I've deleted the 2 lines of foreign key, and rename column `type` inside the migration `Article` to `type_article_id` but still has the same error. You meant that right ?

Comment: So, i did change in phpmyadmin all the table id name (example: type_article_id for type_article, theme_id for theme and so on). I did change these inside my models. I do not have the error. BUT ! I do show errosr in my view class with `$errors->all()` with a `foreach`. It says that `The type article field is required.` But I did but it inside my controller like that https://pastebin.com/tvpqg63m (impossible to put as a comment). I'm using a `foreach` to show all the choice for `type_article` and its working. But I don't really know why it says that `type_article` is required because I put it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not specifying the key to be used for the `belongsTo` relationship. When you do not define this, Eloquent has to assume the name; this naming is done by the relationship method name, `type_article`, + `_id` = `type_article_id`.

You need to tell the relationship to be using a different foreign key for the relationship as it does not fit with the automatic naming via convention:

```
$this->belongsTo(Type_Article::class, 'type');
```

This field should probably be named `type_id` to fit in with conventions better.

> "Eloquent determines the default foreign key name by examining the name of the relationship method and suffixing the method name with a `_` followed by the name of the primary key column. However, if the foreign key on the `Comment` model is not `post_id`, you may pass a custom key name as the second argument to the `belongsTo` method"

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Eloquent - Relationships - One to Many (Inverse)](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse)

You are not showing how you are inserting a record, which is an important thing.

Comment: Hello, first of, thanks for your anwser. Here is my relationship inside `Article` model `return $this->belongsTo(Type_Article::class, 'type_article_id');` and inside `Type_article` model I have this `return $this->hasMany(Article::class, 'type');`. For my inserting record, here it is (its a bit long so I put it inside a pastebin link) : https://pastebin.com/MazNCJFD I do have this error now `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'type_article' in 'field list'`

Comment: if you changed the foreign key field to match the naming convention based on the name of the relationship method then you don't need to make this adjustment; as you have already resolved the issue by adjusting your schema

Comment: If I understand well, every foreign key inside my `Article` table should end with `id` so for example, my foreign key about the model `Type_article` should be `type_article_id` inside my `Article` table, right ?

Comment: it could be `type_id` and the relationship method could be named `type` if you wanted, but you can actually name the stuff what ever you wanted you would have to override the conventions when defining the relationship though

Comment: `you would have to override the conventions when defining the relationship though`, by adding `_id` its override ? I'm sorry, I do not understand everything..

Comment: Well, I'm really lost here. I did change the column name inside my database, I changed it also in the model of `Type_article` and still have this error `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'type_article' in 'field list'`

Comment: where is the code that is causing this insert? you have not shown that still

Comment: Could we speak in the chat please ? To avoid extended discussions

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227330/discussion-between-leon-and-lagbox).

Comment: The problem was my Eloquent code `$type_articles = Type_article::find($data['typeArticle'])` and you need to put the CORRECT name of each ID of your table inside your model !